Fixing my propane firepit control valve/ignitor
Photos of the igniter and valve: https://imgur.com/a/JWvjeSI
Our propane firepit doesn’t light anymore and trying to find best way to fix or replace parts safely.
The knob was stuck and I had to force it to turn and now can’t tell if gas is on or not. The igniter sounds like it’s clicking but can’t see the spark, but I did try to light manually with a lighter but didn’t work either).
How do I know which replacement parts to get? I figured to try an igniter and a control valve for the gas but how can I make sure I’m using the correct parts?

Find the parts manual for the firepit, or contact the company for parts.

Manufacturer said needed to order a new firepit. I ended up ordering replacement parts on Amazon by just comparing the parts and was able to easily fix. Bought a leak detector to make sure it wasn’t leaking. $20 repair.

If you had to force it open, you broke it, as confirmed by manual lighter atempt, there is no gas.
